# Find the furthest coordinates from Polygon and Calculate distance in Nautical Miles

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, geopy, obspy

I am looking to solve a problem for any given polygons, how to find 2 furthest coordinates pair (this is also known as Maximum Linear Extent) and compute the distance between those 2 furthest coordinates for given polygon in Nautical Miles.

Altough my attempt was not successful below is the code so far what I have tried:

```py
import shapely.geometry as sg
import math
from shapely import Polygon, length
import geopy.distance as distance

# Create the polygon object
t1 = sg.Polygon([(-74.418225663382, 39.36239030236737), # Further Point 1: Atlantic City, NJ
                 (-74.27880733397238, 39.71055595453288),
                 (-74.75681303480502, 40.219387193292164),
                 (-75.4705021020208, 40.60356289498688),
                 (-76.88460230031765, 40.264996135212186), # Further Point 2: Harrisburg, PA
                 (-74.418225663382, 39.36239030236737)])

# Initialize variables to store the furthest coordinates
furthest_pair = None
max_distance = 0

# Iterate through all pairs of coordinates in the polygon
for i, p1 in enumerate(t1.exterior.coords):
    for j, p2 in enumerate(t1.exterior.coords[i+1:]):
        distance = p1.distance(p2)  # Calculate the distance between the points
        if distance > max_distance:
            max_distance = distance
            furthest_pair = (p1, p2)

# Print the furthest coordinates and their distance
print("Furthest coordinates:", furthest_pair)  # This should print 2 furthest coordinates pair 
print("Distance between them:", max_distance) # Distance in Nautical Miles
print("Should be: ", 126.0, "NM")
```

Appreciate any feedback and support with this. Thank you!

Comment: I think the logic is okay, but can I know what is output are you expecting and what are you getting. by this logic.

Comment: What is wrong with the code, as it is? What is the question?

Comment: You didn't say what the problem with your given code was, but do be careful with your names! You use the name distance in `import geopy.distance as distance`, and again in `distance = p1.distance(p2)`.

Comment: For ANURAGRANJAN, I have edited the question for your awareness. Thank you.
@zvone, the code is showing the error below: 
**AttributeError::
/tmp/ipykernel_51076/580192759.py in <module>
     19 for i, p1 in enumerate(t1.exterior.coords):
     20     for j, p2 in enumerate(t1.exterior.coords[i+1:]):
---> 21         distance = p1.distance(p2)  # Calculate the distance between the points
     22         if distance > max_distance:
     23             max_distance = distance

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'distance' **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the intepreter says:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'distance'
```

The reason why is that you write:

```
import geopy.distance as distance
```

But this line means: import `geopy.distance` aka `distance`. This is wrong because I think you would want to import the distance method. This is waht the code should be:

```
from geopy.distance import distance
```

Also the distance method has the following syntax ([official doc](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=distance#module-geopy.distance)): `distance(tuple1, tuple2)`. If you want a distance in nautical miles, use `.nm` at the end of the method.

In summary:

```
import shapely.geometry as sg
from geopy.distance import distance

# Create the polygon object
t1 = sg.Polygon([(-74.418225663382, 39.36239030236737), # Further Point 1: Atlantic City, NJ
                 (-74.27880733397238, 39.71055595453288),
                 (-74.75681303480502, 40.219387193292164),
                 (-75.4705021020208, 40.60356289498688),
                 (-76.88460230031765, 40.264996135212186), # Further Point 2: Harrisburg, PA
                 (-74.418225663382, 39.36239030236737)])

# Initialize variables to store the furthest coordinates
furthest_pair = None
max_distance = 0

# Iterate through all pairs of coordinates in the polygon
for i, p1 in enumerate(t1.exterior.coords):
    for j, p2 in enumerate(t1.exterior.coords[i+1:]):
        dist = distance(p1, p2).nm  # Calculate the distance between the points
        if dist > max_distance:
            max_distance = dist
            furthest_pair = (p1, p2)

# Print the furthest coordinates and their distance
print("Furthest coordinates:", furthest_pair)  # This should print 2 furthest coordinates pair 
print("Distance between them:", max_distance) # Distance in Nautical Miles
print("Should be: ", 126.0, "NM")
```

Answer (score 1):

I can make your code work with three small modifications:

1. Use the distance function from geopy (which you have already imported). You attempted to call `p1.distance(p2)`, but p1 is a tuple and has no function called `distance`. You'll get an error informing you of that. Instead, call
   `distance.distance(p1, p2)`.
2. Eliminate duplicate names. You use the name `distance` in multiple places in your code to mean different things. The first is here:
   `import geopy.distance as distance`
   And the second is here:
   `distance = p1.distance(p2)`
   This effectively gets rid of the `distance` module you imported and replaces it with whatever the distance function returned (a geodesic, I believe). This causes an error the next time the loop goes around and tries to use the module: `AttributeError: 'geodesic' object has no attribute 'distance'`.
   Rename your valiable to `pair_distance` or something like that.
3. Your coordinates are switched. Latitude then Longitude. Your distances will turn out funky if you have it backwards.